# how to destroy an object in unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

how to destroy an object in unity?
I know you have to type the command
Destroy();
but what I'm saying is that I don't know what to put between brackets.
I have tried many different ways:
public GameObject motor;
Destroy(motor);
but it does not work

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class LogRotation : MonoBehaviour
    {

        [System.Serializable] //this will allow us to edit it in the editor
        //a custom class representing a single rotation "element" of the log's rotation pattern
        private class RotationElement
        {
            //to get rid of an obnoxious warning about these fields not being initialized
    #pragma warning disable 0649
            public float Speed;
            public float Duration;
    #pragma warning restore 0649
        }

        [SerializeField] //attribute making private fields editable in the Unity Editor
        //the aforemention full rotation pattern of the log
        private RotationElement[] rotationPattern;

        //this will be set to the Wheel Joint 2D from the LogMotor object
        private WheelJoint2D wheelJoint;
        //something has to actually apply a force to the log through the Wheel Joint 2D
        private JointMotor2D motor;

        private void Awake()
        {
            //setting fields
            wheelJoint = GetComponent<WheelJoint2D>();
            motor = new JointMotor2D();
            //starting an infinitely looping coroutine defined below right when this script loads (awakes)
            StartCoroutine("PlayRotationPattern");
        }

        private IEnumerator PlayRotationPattern()
        {
            int rotationIndex = 0;
            //infinite coroutine loop
            while (true)
            {
                //working with physics, executing as if this was running in a FixedUpdate method
                yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

                motor.motorSpeed = rotationPattern[rotationIndex].Speed;
                //hard coded 10000, feel free to experiment with other torques if you wish
                motor.maxMotorTorque = 10000;
                //set the updated motor to be the motor "sitting" on the Wheel Joint 2D
                wheelJoint.motor = motor;

                //let the motor do its thing for the specified duration
                yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(rotationPattern[rotationIndex].Duration);
                rotationIndex++;
                //infinite loop through the rotationPattern
                rotationIndex = rotationIndex < rotationPattern.Length ? rotationIndex : 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you want to remove the motor? I don't see any Destroy in these codes.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** `Destroy(motor.gameObject)`, but it will *not* work if `JointMotor2D` doesn't inherit `MonoBehaviour`.

---

`Destroy(obj)` can be used to destroy a component too.
You need reference it to the game-object to destroy it.

> `Destroy(GetComponent<RigidBody>())` would remove the RigidBody out of the game-object, rather than removing the object itself.

`Destroy(motor.gameObject)` should do the trick.

But upon seeing your code, it may not.
As it seems like `JointMotor2D` isn't a MonoBehaviour, aka it doesn't exists in the game-world, hence you can't destroy it.

Depending on what your trying to destroy, you have to find a reference to it.
Simplest way is to reference it in the inspector. Or destroy itself if that is already the object you want to destroy:

```cs
// Drag-drop the object in the inspector
[SerializeField] 
private GameObject toDestroyLater;

private void DestroyObject() {
    Destroy(toDestroyLater);

    // Destroys self
    // (Aka, whatever game-object this script is attached to)
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: when i try this method with Destroy(motor.gameObject) i get this error: UnassignedReferenceException: the GameController's knifeObject variable was not assigned. You probably need to assign the knifeObject variable of the GameController script in the inspector. and the last method is not working for me at all